# arangob can't send requests more than 1000

Tags: arangodb

I use arangob for testing ArangoDB performance, but arangob can't send requests more than 1000.
"Total number of operations:" is always 1000.

My terminal output is following.

```
$./arangob --server.endpoint "tcp://127.0.0.1:8529" --delay --requests 50000  --test-case     document --complexity 10  --batch-size 0 --concurrency 1
starting threads...
executing tests...
2014-10-02T06:58:39Z [15498] INFO number of operations: 100
2014-10-02T06:58:39Z [15498] INFO number of operations: 150
2014-10-02T06:58:39Z [15498] INFO number of operations: 200
2014-10-02T06:58:39Z [15498] INFO number of operations: 250
2014-10-02T06:58:39Z [15498] INFO number of operations: 300
2014-10-02T06:58:39Z [15498] INFO number of operations: 350
2014-10-02T06:58:39Z [15498] INFO number of operations: 400
2014-10-02T06:58:39Z [15498] INFO number of operations: 450
2014-10-02T06:58:39Z [15498] INFO number of operations: 500

Total number of operations: 1000, keep alive: yes, async: no, batch size: 0, concurrency level (threads): 1
Test case: document, complexity: 10, database: '_system', collection: 'ArangoBenchmark'
Total request/response duration (sum of all threads): 0.207963 s
Request/response duration (per thread): 0.207963 s
Time needed per operation: 0.000224 s
Time needed per operation per thread: 0.000224 s
Operations per second rate: 4469.890637
Elapsed time since start: 0.223719 s
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Issue seems to be caused by the `--delay` option. Omitting it fixes the issue when I try it.
Will now look into why `delay` causes trouble.

**update**: `--delay` needs a boolean value as its argument, e.g. `--delay true`. Omitting the argument will make the command-line parser interpret the next command line argument as the value for the `--delay` parameter. In your case that is `--requests`, so the `--requests` option will be ignored.

So the command-line should read:

```
./arangob --server.endpoint "tcp://127.0.0.1:8529" --delay true --requests 50000  --test-case document --complexity 10 --batch-size 0 --concurrency 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! With --delay true, arangob is OK.

Comment: ./arangob --server.endpoint "tcp://127.0.0.1:8529" --delay true --requests 50000  --test-case document --complexity 10 --batch-size 0 --concurrency 1       Operations per second rate: 3067.167579

Comment: ./arangob --server.endpoint "tcp://127.0.0.1:8529" --delay true --requests 50000  --test-case document --complexity 10 --batch-size 10 --concurrency 10  Operations per second rate: 19880.179646

Answer (score 0):

Another output is following:

```
$ ./arangob --server.endpoint "tcp://127.0.0.1:8529" --delay --requests 50000  --test-case document --complexity 10  --batch-size 20 --concurrency 1
starting threads...
executing tests...
2014-10-02T07:00:04Z [15556] INFO number of operations: 100
2014-10-02T07:00:04Z [15556] INFO number of operations: 150

Total number of operations: 1000, keep alive: yes, async: no, batch size: 20, concurrency level (threads): 1
Test case: document, complexity: 10, database: '_system', collection: 'ArangoBenchmark'
Total request/response duration (sum of all threads): 0.056860 s
Request/response duration (per thread): 0.056860 s
Time needed per operation: 0.000062 s
Time needed per operation per thread: 0.000062 s
Operations per second rate: 16058.071333
Elapsed time since start: 0.062274 s

$ ./arangob --server.endpoint "tcp://127.0.0.1:8529" --delay --requests 50000  --test-case document --complexity 10  --batch-size 20 --concurrency 10
starting threads...
executing tests...
2014-10-02T07:00:18Z [15568] INFO number of operations: 100

Total number of operations: 1000, keep alive: yes, async: no, batch size: 20, concurrency level (threads): 10
Test case: document, complexity: 10, database: '_system', collection: 'ArangoBenchmark'
Total request/response duration (sum of all threads): 0.339047 s
Request/response duration (per thread): 0.033905 s
Time needed per operation: 0.000041 s
Time needed per operation per thread: 0.000408 s
Operations per second rate: 24507.312513
Elapsed time since start: 0.040804 s
```